# kendo grid override default filter event with custom filter

Tags: telerik-mvc

How can I override mvc kendo grid filter to filter On different type than type column is bound to, or change the way that the condition check
I have already figured out a way to handle filter event but i don't know how filter datasource and refresh grid

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to override the type that you have bound to your column, but you could use this as an alternative to pass down additional data to your controller to override and filter your datasource on the back end. You'd need to wire up an event that would trigger the read event on your grid. You could add this to your datasource on the grid.

```
dataSource.Read(read => read.Action("actionName","controllerName").Data("GetExtraDataToFilterBy"));
```

Then Implement a function that grabs data from your filter you want to use.

```
function GetExtraDataToFilterBy(o) {
var data= $('#someDataFieldToFilter').is(':checked');
return {
    filterData: data
}
```

}

```
function eventToRefreshGrid() {
    $("#yourGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
}
```